# What are the character functions of $\mathbb{Z}_N \times \mathbb{Z}_N$ ?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups

$\mathbb{Z}_N \times \mathbb{Z}_N$ is an Abelian group which I can think of to consist of all tuples of the form $(\omega ^a, \omega^b)$ where $0 \leq a,b \leq (N-1)$ and $\omega = e^{ \frac{2 \pi i }{N}}$. And the group operation is the usual complex number multiplication done coordinate-wise here.

- Is the above description right?

Now since this is an Abelian group each element of it is in an equivalence class of its own ubder the conjugation action and hence there are $N^2$ equivalence classes. Corresponding to each class/element $(\omega ^a, \omega^b)$ there is an one-dimensional irreducible representation of the group given as $\rho_{(\omega ^a, \omega^b)} : \mathbb{Z}_N \times \mathbb{Z}_N \rightarrow GL_1(\mathbb{C}) $ and hence there are $N^2$ character functions $\chi _{(\omega ^a, \omega^b) } : \mathbb{Z}_N \times \mathbb{Z}_N \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ mapping,

$$\chi_{(\omega ^a, \omega^b)  }[ (\omega ^c, \omega^d) ] = Tr[\rho_{(\omega ^a, \omega^b)  } [(\omega ^c, \omega^d)  ] ]$$

- Is the above indexing correct?
- But I am not very clear as to what is the description of these functions $\rho_{(\omega ^a, \omega^b)  } [(\omega ^c, \omega^d)  ] : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $Tr[\rho_{(\omega ^a, \omega^b)  } [(\omega ^c, \omega^d)  ] ]$

  Can someone kindly give an explicit description/evaluation of the above two quantities?

Comment: The characters are $(\omega^c, \omega^d) \mapsto \omega^{ab + cd}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks And any proof for this?  And the $\rho_{( \omega^a, \omega^b )}$ map?

Comment: A one-dimensional representation is the same thing as its character. The proof is straightforward and there are lots of ways to do it; I encourage you to try it yourself as an exercise.